# Snowflake External function with Lamdba

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When we create an external function to call lambda to fetch let's say an encryption key to decrypt a particular column in a snowflake table, does the LAMBDA get triggered for each row in the table? Or once the encryption key is retrieved, it is available for the entire session

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would trigger one call to get the encryption key per batch (of up to 4000 rows) and use that for each row in the batch.